# What is the meaning of the sqlite Blob literal x'007800'?

Tags: sql, sqlite, hex

Sqlite has the [blob datatype](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)  which stores data as hex-strings. You can write [blob literals](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) using the `x'<hexadecimal numbers>'` notation.

The docs about this:

> BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. Example: X'53514C697465'

This way you can write for example in the sqlite CLI

```sql
sqlite> SELECT x'313233';
123
sqlite>
```

As SQLite will automatically transform the hexadecimal numbers 31-32-33 into their ASCII counterparts for the decimal numbers 49, 50 and 51, which are "1", "2" and "3".

Now as part of a test-suite I am maintaining from somebody else there is a test that uses `x'007800'` and claims it to be a NULL value of some sort.

In fact, running that value in an sqlite console returns nothing:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT x'007800';

sqlite>
```

I am somewhat confused as to what the meaning behind that hexadecimal is (?). Googling around, I could find no special meaning attached to that particular number. It appears to be a representation of `"\0x\0"`, which I similarly can't extract any meaning from.

What is the meaning of `x'007800'` and/or `"\0x\0"` ?

Comment: x'007800' means three bytes
 `00` , `78` and `00` in hexadecimal, which are equal to ASCII characters null (\0) and x.

You can refer the table here.
https://www.eso.org/~ndelmott/ascii.html

Comment: To be on the safe side, do those have *any* connection to null in some manner, outside of the 2 "nulls" that surround the x? Does that have any special meaning? The reason I'm so stuck on null is due to the test name being `select blob with nul` which I can't make heads or tails of (the test literally just executes the given SQL query I wrote about and checks if it returns a Blob type with the contents "\0x\0".)

Comment: `x'007800'` is not NULL: https://dbfiddle.uk/e4ha8gm0

Comment: @Philipp  I am really not sure about that :) But, I believe; It does not have any connection to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of x'007800' and/or "\0x\0" ?

The blob literal `x'007800'` means three bytes 00, 78 and 00 in hexadecimal,
which are equal to ASCII characters null `(\0)` and `x`.

You can [refer the table here](https://www.eso.org/%7Endelmott/ascii.html).

```
CharacterName    Char     Code    Decimal     Binary      Hex
Null             NUL      Ctrl@   0           00000000    00
Lower-case X     x        X       120         01111000    78
```